# Dockerfile/ Docker Compose for multiple projects with different ports

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I need your suggestions to architect a solution. I have a solution(.NET Core) with 5 API projects.

```
Solution 
   Project 1
   Project 2 
   Project 3 
   Project 4 
   Project 5
```

which runs on different ports, Like

```
http://localhost:10500/api/values , 
http://localhost:10501/api/values .. so on
http://localhost:10504/api/values
```

(Only the post number changes )

Requirement is to dockerize this solution and run in Kubernetes cluster via Kube Ingress, what is better way of Implementing?

1) Create one Image deploy the solution and EXpose multiple ports?

2) Use Docker COmpose and build proj1 Export port, build project 2 expose port 2 etc?

Any ideas much appreciated, please?

Comment: In my opinion, Docker-compose would more better for this. All the definitions will be at same place

Comment: If you need different entry ports, Kubernetes is not needed. You can use it anyway, but mainly you should use `docker-compose`. In `docker-compose.yml` file, you'll be able to define a service for each project, for example, and although they build from the same image, you can specify a different port mapping in `ports:`section.

Answer (score 1):

I think the right solution depends on the requirements. Choosing option 1 would have those consequences:

- one container with all services within, if it crashes, all services are down
- scaling: each service will be scaled up, even if only one of them has to handle most of the traffic.
- updates: changes in one service result in the »redeployment« of all the others within the container.
- monitoring: Gathering metrics for each service can be gained based on the running containers, if all services run in one container you can monitor them all as one, or you need to implement you own way to separate logs.

In short: Since you can use a dedicated Image for each service, if you use `docker-compose`, you have a much finer granularity for updates, scaling and monitoring.

Comment: Also, creating multiple images enables you to use your API projects on multiple servers. As you mentionned Kubernetes, it means that you can have a cluster. Serving your APIs on different nodes will help you with load balancing.